# Computing Probability Involving a Function of a Variable

Tags: probability

> The time until failure, $T$, of a product is modeled by a uniform distribution on $[0,10]$. An extended warranty pays a benefit of $100$ if failure occurs between time $t = 1.5$ and $t=8$. The present value, $W$, of this benefit is
>   $$W = \begin{cases}
> 0,& \text{for } 0\leq T<1.5\\
> 100e^{-0.04T},& \text{for } 1.5 \leq T<8\\
> 0,&  \text{for } 8\leq T\leq 10.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Calculate $P(W<79).$

I wrote down the following:

\begin{align}
P(W < 79) \ \ & = \ \ P(W < 79 \ | \ T < 1.5)P(T < 1.5) \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ + P(W < 79 \ | \ 1.5 < T < 8)P(1.5 < T < 8) \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ + P(W < 79 \ | \ 8 < T)P(8 < T) \\
& = \ \ .35 + .65 \cdot P(W < 79 \ | \ 1.5 < T < 8) \\
& = \ \ .35 + .65 \cdot P\left( \tfrac{-\ln 0.79}{.04} < T < 8 \right)
\end{align}

Apparently, the last line is wrong.  Rather, it should be:

\begin{align}
.35 + .65 \cdot P(W < 79 \ | \ 1.5 < T < 8) \ \ & = \ \ .35 + .65 \cdot \frac{P(W < 79 \ \text{and} \ 1.5 < T < 8)}{P(1.5 < T < 8)} \\
& = \ \ .35 + P(W < 79 \ \text{and} \ 1.5 < T < 8) \\
& = \ \ .35 + P \left( \tfrac{-\ln 0.79}{0.04} < T < 8 \right)
\end{align}

So, I need to convert the conditional probability before applying $W = 100e^{-0.04T}$.  But on the other hand, it is perfectly fine to write, say:

\begin{align}
P(X + Y \le c) \ \ & = \ \ \sum_{k} P(X + Y \le c \ | \ Y = k)P(Y = k) \\
& = \ \ \sum_{k} P(X \le c - k)P(Y = k)
\end{align}

Can someone kindly explain what is the difference between the two cases?

Comment: The difference is independence.  In the last case, $X,Y$ are independent, where as $W,T$ are quite dependent.

Comment: Please don't post images. They are not searchable.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}P(X+Y\leq c) &= \sum_{k}P(X+Y\leq c, Y=k) \\
& = \sum_{k}P(X\leq c-k, Y=k) \\
&= \sum_{k} P(X\leq c-k|Y=k)P(Y=k)\end{align}$$

Now, in the above equation, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X\leq c-k|Y=k) = P(X\leq c-k)$ otherwise the term stays like that only.